# Java In-memory database with SQL Server support

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, integration-testing, in-memory-database

Which of the available in-memory databases has best support for SQL Server specific features?

I've been trying with H2, but had problems for example with escaping column names: in all of our our sql queries we use the (non-standard) [FIELDNAME] instead of "FIELDNAME". This is apparently not supported by H2. There might be also other non-standard features that might be used, so I wonder if anybody knows of a specific database which targets compatibility with SQL Server.

To put this into context I'm using maven and the maven-sql-plugin to create the database before running the tests.

I've been looking at

- H2
- HSQL
- Derby

but could not determine which one had best support for SQL Server or if there are others to look at.

Comment: Why not run tests on your SQL Server development database? I have used this strategy (although with Oracle and PostgreSQL) in several projects, and it always worked well. You save the start-up cost of creating an in-memory database + base data load, and avoid all DB compatibility issues.

Comment: @Rogério: I want to be able to run the tests automatically on Jenkins and be 100% sure that no one else is running against the same database at the same time and possibly modifying the data. What you are suggesting is how we actually are doing it right now and I'd like to improve on that.

Comment: Your tests should never commit a transaction to the database. That way, they will always run in isolation for each other, as it must be.

Comment: ... unless we are talking about functional/web/UI tests which need to commit transactions. In this case, sure, a shared db is not going to be an option. This is one of the reasons I avoid such tests (others being they are too slow and more fragile than rollback-only integration tests).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've actually found that H2 has different compatibility modes that can be set in the connection string. For example:

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer
```

This seems to solve my specific issue with escaping column names.

For future reference one can look at the [documentation on compatibility modes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) to see which features are supported for which databases.

However some SQL Server functions like SYSDATETIME() are **not** supported.

Comment: As a side note: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can be used as a drop in replacement for `SYSDATETIME()` (without parentheses). Its seems to be implemented in both H2 and MSSQL.